Mail sending failed: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`98-81-57-227.cprapid.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.gmail.com'
Title: "Laravel Email Configuration Not Working on AWS WHM cPanel Server"
Body: "I am using AWS WHM cPanel Shared hosting server to send emails in my Laravel application. Below is my .env configuration for SMTP using Gmail:
Copy code
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=finderspage11@gmail.com
MAIL_USERNAME=finderspage11@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="my_password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_DEBUG=true

I have tried the following steps with AWS tech support:
Verified that port 587 is open
Double-checked Gmail SMTP settings
Confirmed that MAIL_PASSWORD is correct
However, I still can’t send emails. Could someone suggest a solution?

This question is similar to: PHPMailer generates PHP Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate did not match expected. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think the problem is that Gmail by default closing smtp forwarding, so did you check the gmail settings ?

In your Google/Gmail account, go to Settings - See all settings.
Select the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab.
Under the IMAP access section, toggle on the option to Enable IMAP.


